# push the results of a ajax query into another object

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to push the results of an AJAX query into another object but can't seem to do it.

Below is my Javascript code:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/Orion/Services/Information.asmx/QueryWithParameters',
  data: params,
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (response) {
    //console.table(response);
    var results1 = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < response.d.Rows.length; i++) {
      results1.push({response.d.Rows[i][0], response.d.Rows[i][1]});
    }
    console.table(results1);
  },
});
```

Comment: `results1` is an object and the push method works on an array. Try replacing, `var results1 = {};` to `var results1 = [];`

Comment: Your `.push()` call also isn't valid. `{response.d.Rows[i][0], response.d.Rows[i][1]}` isn't a valid object, you'd need to define some keys if you want to push an object. See [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Comment: Thannks @romellem